What TV show on real-life mysteries mentioned a child time-traveller in a photo of the Gettysburg Address?
I need help finding a television program. I believe it was like "In Search Of" which dealt with real life mysteries in a scientific format. It was a television show on time travel. The show was on years ago, when I was young. I am guessing between 1972 to 1989.
Here is the key: there was a photograph of the Gettysburg Address in the television program. The commentator noted that the child in the centre of the photo was a time traveller, but his identity would not be revealed. This was said as a statement of fact. The program could have been on TV only that one time, because of this statement.
I guess I would need a list of all kinds of television programs from that time period. Any help would be appreciated. 

What country & language? Was it aimed at adults or children?

I'm guessing the program referred to this story?

Closed the duplicate question, leaving this one open.  Because one was migrated from SciFi, you may be editing two questions on Movies now.  Please just edit this one.

hello iandotkelly - What would you suggest I ask?  I cannot remember the name of the program.  If I could, I would research the episode myself.  The statement made by the commentator was what made the program stand out.  Think of the amount of programs made over the years.  So, what do you believe would narrow the search down?  Thank you.

I'm not suggesting anything - I'm just saying that they migrated your SciFi question to here, so I closed it as a duplicate.  I think you just need to leave it a day or two to see whether someone knows.

BTW - if you put an @ before someone's name - they will get a notification, so you could put @iandotkelly, and I would be notified that you'd directed a comment at me.

Perhaps an episode of Conspiracy Theory with Jesse Ventura titled Time Travel?

Ventura investigates rumors that the government has developed secret time travel technology beginning with the Philadelphia Experiment and Montauk Project and that it has been used as a weapon to alter historical events. Later he meets Andrew D. Basiago, a man who claims that as a child, he was "chrononaut" working for his father at the Los Alamos National Laboratory on a DARPA experiment called "Project Pegasus" and was sent back in time to meet historical figures such as George Washington and Abraham Lincoln.


Sorry, the program aired from the late 1970's to the late 1980's.
